# converting a List<String> property to individual values in a CSV export from GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, csv

I have a list of String inside a class in my App Engine project, and in the database export to a CSV (through bulkloader.yaml) the resulting field is the proper List.
The problem is that this CSV is imported again into a MySQL database and such field remains as a single list of strings.

Any idea about how to tweak the .yaml config_file to generate a tuple for every string?

Comment: Show some code please. At least the input format and output format.

Comment: Also explain "the resulting field is the proper List" and "such field remains as a single list of strings".

Comment: I have User and FavouriteMeal classes, in a N:N relationship, therefore, following doc recommendations I maintain a List<String> on User to store FavouriteMeal's refs. Then I need to backup the datastore on a MySQL db so I download User entities as CSV using the appcfg.py . Such List<String> is exported in the CSV as one field following this format:  'user1,"[id2323, id4523, id5645]"' . I'd prefer a one-per-row in order to import them on the db as pairs user-favid, for example: 'user1, id2323', 'user1, id4523', 'user1, id5645' , and I was wondering how do that with the appcfg.py. Thanks again!

Comment: I wrote some [bulkloader helper](http://code.google.com/p/bulkloader-gdata-connector/source/browse/bulk_helper.py) functions a while ago. Check out `list_to_json` and `json_to_list` to see how I wrote some custom converters. I assume you'd need a list_to_sql converter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make the bulkloader export multiple rows for a single entity using the YAML configuration. You'll either need to write a custom exporter, or a custom converter - see the [bulkloader source](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fpython%2Fgoogle%2Fappengine%2Fext%2Fbulkload) for details (in the docstrings).

Comment: Hi, in fact I was thinking about a postprocess phase using PERL/Awk to duplicate rows but finally I just redefined entities`s relationship to a more SQL-oriented approach. Thanks all!